# angular ui bootstrap, $scope.$watch doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm playing with angular datekeeper, and trying to set basic function of $watch which will show me, some information in console.log. 
This function should show to me if my date is lesser than my maxDate so show me in console "wrong date". I've read a documentation about $watch but couldn't figure out.
What am i doing wrong? 
this is link on    `enter code here` [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/iezTdjZpkZUy1CIjINE9?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the $scope. in front of dt in your watch

```
$scope.$watch ('$scope.dt', function(){
    if($scope.dt < $scope.maxDate){
      console.log('wrong date')
    }
  })
```

should be:

```
$scope.$watch ('dt', function(){
    if($scope.dt < $scope.maxDate){
      console.log('wrong date')
    }
  })
```